# Cutting a time elapsed variable into manageable things

Tags: r

```
flight_time
    11:42:00
    19:37:06
    18:11:17
```

I am having trouble working with the time played variable in the dataset. I can't seem to figure out how to get R to treat this value as a numeric.

Apologies if this has been asked before.

EDIT:

Okay well given the stuff posted below I've realised there's a few things I didn't know/check before.

First of all this is  a factor variable. I read through the lubridate package documentation, and since I want to perform arithmetic operations (if this is the right terminology) I believe the duration function is the correct one.

However looking at the examples - I am not entirely sure what the syntax is for applying this to a whole column in a large(ish) data from. Since I have 4.5k observations, I'm not sure exactly how to appply this. I don't need an excessive amount of granularity - ideally even hours and minutes are fine.

So I'm thinking I would want my code to look like:

conversion from factor variable to character string > conversion from character string to duration/as.numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#dummy data with factors
df <- data.frame(flight_time=c("11:42:00","19:37:06","18:11:17"))

#add Seconds column
df$Seconds <- 
  sapply(as.character(df$flight_time), function(i)
    sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(i,":"))) * c(60^2,60,1)))

#result
df
#   flight_time Seconds
# 1    11:42:00   42120
# 2    19:37:06   70626
# 3    18:11:17   65477
```

Comment: That just returns the seconds from `res` as the numeric. I'm assuming that @Anaryl wants the whole string converted to a numeric. Looking at `str(res)`, the sum of `res@hour`, `res@minute` and `res@.Data` (seconds), properly converted to a constant scale, will do what he wants. I'm not too familiar with lubridate but I don't see a simple way to do it in Hadley's vignette.

Comment: In your second example, it should be (1, 1/60, 1/(60*60)) or (60, 1, 1/60) or (60*60, 60, 1), the (60, 60, 60) just multiples everything (hours, minutes and seconds) by 60. For example, 18:11:17 should be 65477 s or 1091.28 min or 18.19 hours. Same with the `rowSums` multiplier. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Is this a whole bloc or is the second a standalone code - jusst with the first assignment - I need to cover something like four and a half thousand observations - am I correct in assuming I can pass in the subset like x <- c(dataset$flight_time) ?

Comment: If it's any assistance the data set can be found here
http://www.reddit.com/r/starcitizen/comments/36gomg/here_is_the_raw_stats_data_season_8_including_cc/

Comment: Sorry if I'm over commenting. So I got to apply it to the whole data frame, that actually wasn't a problem, and it's added a new var called 'flight_time_int" - that shows the duration in the same format....

But  I think it works! Let me play with it some before confirming that

Comment: @Anaryl see edit it should be ok now, thanks to iacobus's comment.

Comment: It looks pretty good, just a final question, given that there is such a large number of observations for flgiht_time_int - and i want to cut these into a bucket to make them more observable on a graph - I suppose i would cut the variable - is there a wildcard syntax that supports this?

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for being a bother by the way

Comment: Hey there, sorry to bother you again, but i ran your code and it seems to have just populated the new variable with the dummy data listed above, and also returns an error

 Error in strsplit(i, ":") : non-character argument 

http://pastebin.com/sEbRhvk4
I've pasted by interpreted solution in the pastebin above ... no doubt i  have missed something

Comment: Ignore the `data.frame` bit, I used it to create an example data. Only use `sapply` bit.